# Match strings of different length in two lists of different length

Tags: python, string, list

Say I have two flat lists of strings:

```
a = ["today", "I", "want", "to", "eat", "some", "cake."]
b = ["to", "da", "y", "I", "wa", "nt", "to", "ea", "t", "some", "ca", "ke", "."]
```

Where in list `b` some strings (not all) of list `a` are split into multiple substrings. Note that the substrings in `b` that correspond to the strings in `a` are adjacent and in the same order, as in the example above.

I want to obtain a list `c` where the substrings in `b` that correspond to a single string in `a` are put together in a sublist:

```
c = [["to", "da", "y"], ["I"], ["wa", "nt"], ["to"], ["ea", "t"], ["some"], ["ca", "ke", "."]]
```

Unfortunately I don't have any code to share since I don't know how to approach this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You state that *"in list `b` some strings of list `a` are split into multiple substrings."* Is it some strings or all strings? And are they in the same order in `b` as in `a`?

Comment: Iterate over words in `a`
For each word test use `word.startswith()` to compare with each element of `b` (another loop).
It's a good starting point.
Then you should think how you can achieve the full answer by removing the prefix and repeat the process until a full word has been reconstructed.

Comment: Are all the substrings adjacent in *b*?

Comment: Yes, the substrings are adjacent and yes, they are in the same order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ["today", "I", "want", "to", "eat", "some", "cake."]
b = ["to", "da", "y", "I", "wa", "nt", "to", "ea", "t", "some", "ca", "ke", "."]
c = []

for element in a:
    temp_list = []
    while "".join(temp_list) != element:
        temp_list.append(b.pop(0))
    c.append(temp_list)
```

Value of c:

```
[['to', 'da', 'y'],
 ['I'],
 ['wa', 'nt'],
 ['to'],
 ['ea', 't'],
 ['some'],
 ['ca', 'ke', '.']]
```

I don't know if there is any other clever way to do it. Just use .pop(0) to save u a bit of code

Comment: Assume that substrings in `b` are adjacents.
You should mention it.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient, especially in the repeated joining of the same elements in `temp_list` and the list popping at index 0 in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

@Ben.S.'s answer works but costs *O(m x n x k)* in time complexity, where *m* and *n* are the lengths of the two lists and *k* is the average length of the words.

A more efficient approach that solves the problem in a time complexity of *O(n)* is to keep appending word fragments from `b` to the last sub-list of a new list, but keep track of the total length of fragments appended to the last sub-list and append a new sub-list when the total length equals the length of the corresponding word in `a`:

```
c = []
for i in b:
    if not c or length == target:
        length = 0
        target = len(a[len(c)])
        c.append([])
    length += len(i)
    c[-1].append(i)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ExoticConsiderateSearchservice